# Cannot download old backup from Gmail as it's an archive

Tags: security, gmail, archiving, attachments

Back in 2007/2008 I emailed myself a backup of an important file. It was stored in a password protected RAR archive. I am unable to download the attachment or forward it and given the reason

> Anti-virus warning - 1 attachment contains a virus or blocked file.
>   Downloading this attachment is disabled. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en)

How can I access my file?

Do I understand correct, Gmail doesn't allow password-protected archives? I find this silly as it must allow encrypted attachments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all messages via [IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en) (e.g. using Thunderbird or Windows Mail), with no antivirus checks or other kinds of filtering.

Also try one of the following, in case they might have forgotten to add the same antivirus checks:

- Google [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com/)
- Gmail's [HTML-only](https://mail.google.com/mail/h/) version
- Gmail's old [mobile](https://mail.google.com/mail/x/) version

Comment: IMAP method worked, though the links to old versions did still scan for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the Android Gmail app. Put it in drive if you like.